# MarkLogic connecting to Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, marklogic

I know you can connect Tableau to Marklogic by modelling your Marklogic data as a SQL view and connecting through the ODBC connector in Tableau.

We have had problems using this approach to connect our ML data to Tableau as our MarkLogic databases have tens of millions of documents(mapped to rows in the view) and the Tableau ODBC connector times out trying to import this data. Has anyone experienced similar issues and know of a workaround while still using the MarkLogic SQL views?

I have read that it also possible to connect to Marklogic from Tableau using the web data connector although I cannot find much detailed documentation on this and Marklogic seem to push the SQL/ODBC connector as the way to connect to Tableau. Is this a better option? Does anyone know where there is detailed documentation on this?

Finally, we have been able to extract the ML data into a text file and import that into Tableau. We can use this approach going forward but would prefer to connect directly from Tableau to MarkLogic. Any comments on whether that should be possible given our MarkLogic DB sizes would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_marklogic.html
@Robert Are you using the generic ODBC connector when connecting, or the MarkLogic specific one.  Not sure if that'll make a difference.  Also, when the timeout occurs, is it Tableau or Marklogic that terminates the connection?  My understanding is tableau Desktop can chug along for hours, and Tableau sever parameters can be modified to get over the 2 hour default limit.